# Segmentation fault on heroku when requesting some https sites

Tags: ruby, heroku, openssl

I am not sure this is a Heroku's OS bug. When I opened a HTTPS connection from Heroku to this site: https://www.economicclub.ca/events/ by ruby. Heroku's process crashed. Using begin/rescue does not work this case. Below is my test code.

https://gist.github.com/jacobdam/9244453

I tried with ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0. The error is still happening.

Anyone has a solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also seen this with ruby 2.0.0 and 2.1.1, but 2.1.0 does not seem to be affected. It throws an error rather than segfaulting:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: (null)
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `block in connect'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:920:in `connect'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:583:in `start'
    from (irb):7
```

So, using 2.1.0 is a possible workaround. I've asked heroku support, so we'll see whether they come up with anything else.

Update, following response from Heroku support: This is probably the relevant ruby bug:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9592 . It's only an issue with some older versions of OpenSSL, and heroku is apparently running one of them. Another workaround is to fix ruby to a particular patch level in your Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.1.1', patchlevel: '0'
```

or

```
ruby '2.0.0', patchlevel: '353'
```

do not appear to have this problem.

Comment: Do you know if `2.1.1.p0` is vulnerable to heartbleed?